# Cannot boot windows 8 from SSD

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, boot, ssd

part list: http://uk.pcpartpicker.com/p/k7z2Bm

My SSD is listed in the windows 8 installation setup when I attempt to install (although the 3TB spinner seems to have 2 unallocated sectors for some reason). But it says I can't install it on this drive.

I've gone into the bios and seen that AHCI is enabled.

I've tried swapping the SATA cables/slots for the drives but it still doesn't appear as a valid boot option (as the spinner does).

It then sometimes shows the mobo splash screen at least four times before actually doing something. Is that normal?

When I reboot a random amount of times, it suddenly says it can put windows on that drive, so I do so. After a successful installation, I then reboot and am confronted with "reboot and select proper boot device".

My Mobo is up to date and the firmware upgrade for the ssd cannot find the ssd so I can't upgrade that!

I've done this twice now and on the verge of giving up and phoning Crucial support.

Please. Can anyone help here?

Comment: Try update mobo BIOS and SSD firmware to latest.

Comment: http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=4953&dl=1&RWD=0#bios

http://www.crucial.com/usa/en/support-ssd

Comment: It also would be good to put hardware info of your computer.

Comment: My mobo is already F5 up-to-date and I can't update the ssd because the firmware thing can't find it! And I've posted my specs at the top

Comment: Don't just down vote me for me reason. I'm having real trouble here and I've given all available information!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out CSM mode needed to be enabled in the bios!